# Why on Grails 3.3.3 a redirect action pass also HTML form parameters?

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

I have a simple Grails web application with a couple of controllers.
All works fine with grails 3.2.6, but after upgrading to Grails 3.3.3 I notice a strange behavior on HTML form post action.

For example, for a domain object called Subscriber, after editing an instance I see on my browser navigation bar:

```
subscriber/show/16?_method=PUT&version=2&username=test[......]
```

The controller snippet (a standard scaffolding controller) is

```
@Transactional
def update(Subscriber subscriber) {
    if (subscriber == null) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        notFound()
        return
    }

    if (subscriber.hasErrors()) {
        transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
        respond subscriber.errors, view:'edit'
        return
    }

    subscriber.save(flush:true)

    request.withFormat {
        form multipartForm {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'subscriber.label', default: 'Subscriber'), subscriber.id])
            redirect subscriber
        }
        '*'{ respond subscriber, [status: OK] }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a know bug 

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10965

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug which has been fixed and the fix should be included in Grails 3.3.4.

See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10965.

Comment: FYI... I believe that 3.3.3 is the only release that has this behavior in it.

Comment: With 3.3.2 the bug does not exists, but on 3.3.4 it seems that someone has again this issue:
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10965#issuecomment-378697259

Comment: @Sarbyn Agreed.  I don't think StackOverflow is the proper forum for discussing the status of the ticket.  Please take the conversation to our issue tracker.